# pandas to numpy giving none when i try to do dtype.field instead of the number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe

```
y_train= pd_train.loc[:,["death","TTE"]]
```

It contains 2 columns death and tte

Now I convert it to numpy by using

```
y = y_train.values
```

But next when i try to print

```
print(Y.dtype.fields)
```

I get None instead of the 2 fields i.e the 2 columns.

I am new to numpy. Can you guys please help me I know I am making some basic mistake.

Comment: `numpy` doesn't handle field/column names. It looks like `dtype` happens to have this property, but it is definitely not related to column names in the original dataframe

Comment: Use `to_numpy`.

Comment: `to_records` produces a structured array.  `values` or `to_numpy()` (without compound dtype) produces a 2d array with simple dtype.

Answer (score 1):

`None` is expected. You are storing only the values (not the axes labels) into `y`, also a `dtype` field is not the same thing as a column name. The numpy array therefore has no fields to return. This is well described in the documentation:

1. [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)
2. [numpy.dtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html)
3. [numpy.dtype.fields](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.fields.html)

Also, note that `to_numpy` is preferred over the `values` method.

Comment: '''if not isinstance(y, numpy.ndarray) or y.dtype.fields is None or len(y.dtype.fields) != 2'''

My code fails because of the above... I need the pandas dataframe to be passed such that this condition passes. Can you please let me know how to do that? Like convert pandas to numpy that satisfies above command.

Comment: If you want column names, work with the DataFrame instance (i.e. keep pandas). Then, create a condition that is satisfied based on the object's methods, not an object that satisfies the condition.